# Error access picklist Field [vTiger v 7.4.0]

Tags: vtiger, picklist

while access picklist Field, i can't see anything. here is the following screenshoot

[only show menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt2pz.png)

i use NGINX server with 7.4 PHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by running the query

***SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));'''***

or by adding ***sql_mode=''*** to my my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug this issue by **enabling the error_reporting** from **config.inc.php** file on your server and try to resolve the issue once you identified the error from the screen. You can find a line in **config.inc.php** file similar below.

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

In case, need any help with that issue, you can modify your question.